# После обновления laravel 5.2 до laravel 5.3 перестало работать dependency injection

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

Роут:

```
$group->put('/edit/{product}', [
   'as'  => 'admin.product.update',
   'uses'=>'ProductController@update',
]);
```

Метод в контроллере:

```
public function update(ProductRequest $request, Product $product){
   ...
}
```

После обновления laravel 5.2 до версии 5.3 перестала работать эта конструкция.
В переменной $product приходит пустая модель Product.

Comment: `App\Product $product` попробуйте; и причем тут _dependency injection_?

Comment: @InDevX Прошу прощения, скорее всего я ошибся. Не могли бы вы подсказать как это правильно называется?
`App\Product $product` не помогло

Comment: Это роут с параметрами. Оставьте только $product - так видит?

Comment: Да, если оставляю $product приходит id. Так же если ищу этот id через Product::find(), то продукт находит как нужно

Comment: Какой namespace у модели Product?

Comment: `namespace App\Models\Admin;`
В функцию подставлял этот путь

Comment: Модель находится в папке Admin

Comment: И вы с ним пробовали? `App\Models\Admin\Product $product`

Comment: Да, так и пробовал